# Nginx Timeout. 502 Bad Gateway. Laravel. Connection reset by peer while reading response header from upstream

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5

If someone can help me, I’ll  be very appreciated. I have one GET request to the API, which takes some time for execution. If request takes less than 60 seconds, all work fine. But if I have more than 60 seconds, I get an error
file_get_contents( = my request =): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway

In log: Connection reset by peer while reading response header from upstream

I read a lot of posts and articles, but nothing works. Average time when I get answer from the API is about 70-80 seconds. I use Laravel (php) and nginx.

My script:

```html
$urlRequest = getenv('URLFORAPI').'/search_name?first_name='.$first_name.'&last_name='.$second_name.'&middle_name='.$third_name.'&regionId='.$regionId; 
$result = file_get_contents($urlRequest); 
$array = json_decode($result, true);
```

In the log file:

```
2019/09/26 18:29:31 [error] 26366#26366: *19 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: = my ip =, server: = my server =, request:$

2019/09/26 18:37:39 [error] 26731#26731: *23 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: = my ip =, server: = my server =, request:$

2019/09/27 06:21:07 [error] 7118#7118: *48 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: = my ip =, server: = my server =, request: "$

2019/09/27 07:59:12 [error] 13498#13498: *1 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client:= my ip =, server: = my server =, request: $

2019/09/27 08:12:47 [error] 1069#1069: *3 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: = my ip =, server: = my server =, request: "G$

2019/09/27 12:24:42 [error] 8235#8235: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: = my ip =, server: = my server =, request: "GET /images/icons/f$
```

Added to php.ini:

```
memory_limit = 8192M
default_socket_timeout = 600
max_execution_time = -1
max_input_time = -1
```

I added to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
keepalive_timeout  600;
worker_connections  1024;
client_max_body_size   100m;
client_header_timeout 1200s;
client_body_timeout 1200s;
keepalive_requests 10000;
proxy_connect_timeout 1200s;
proxy_send_timeout 1200s;
proxy_read_timeout 1200s;
send_timeout 1200s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 900s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 900s;
```

/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

```
pm.max_children = 40
pm.start_servers = 15
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 25
pm.max_requests = 500
request_terminate_timeout = 5m
request_slowlog_timeout = 5m
```

set_time_limit(0)  didn’t work.

After all changes sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload and sudo service php7.3-fpm restart

I’m frustrated about it. It took me hours to fix it. Have ideas?

Comment: any update? please update if you found a solution